# Ajax post call to a rest service through servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, servlets

I have a little problem:
I'm developing a jQuery Mobile app and i need to make an ajax post call to a rest service.
I create the pages dynamically using servlets.

I tried to make the ajax call to the rest url:

```
http://localhost:8181/myRestServicePath/func?key=value
```

from a page whit the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Mypage
```

but i get a cross-orign error from the browser.

So i'm tryng to perform this call, passing through a Java servlet using the doPost() method.

Now, my intent is to make an ajax post call from

```
 http://localhost:8080/Mypage
```

to:

```
 http://localhost:8080/myServletPath/func?key=value
```

and this servlet should redirect the POST request to my RestService:

```
http://localhost:8181/myRestServicePath/func?key=value
```

How can i perform this redirection?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at keeping your rest service and the other servlets on the same port? This would be the typical configuration and resolves your difficulty.

Comment: @MalcolmSmith i can't register both servlets and rest services on the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several ways to achieve that. I am just sharing 2 commons possibilities as below.

**For POST requests:-**
You will need to use Apache HTTPClient in your servlet to send the request to web services and get a response. After getting the response you can send that response to your page.

**For GET Requests:-**

You don't need extra servlet for cross domain request. You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

jQuery example:

```
$.ajax({
     url:"http://localhost:8080/myServletPath/func?key=value",
     dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
     success:function(json){
         // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     },
});
```

For back end example visit [Java J2EE Tutorial for Cross Domain JSONP](http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2012/05/solving-cross-domain-problem-using.html)

Comment: I do not want to use jsonp, i need to use json.

Comment: Servlet will be sending response as response.setContentType("text/javascript");
For details visist http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2012/05/solving-cross-domain-problem-using.html

Comment: It will be a JSON response you don't have to worry about anything. Just send the callback method name as well.
Even if you don't specify the call back method name, jQuery will handle that as well for you :)

Comment: @JaffarRamay my rest method is made for parse an URL like what i wrote in my question, and, above all, jsonp don't support POST.

Comment: @JaffarRamay Yes, thanks. I'm finding out about Apache HTTPClient.

Comment: @feazzu U r welcome :)
If answer resolves your question/problem then you are supposed to accept that answer for the sake of other users/community.